# Angularjs Reload partial view gives 'object not found' error in official docs example

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Following the [example in official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route), I find that the partial view rendered doesn't work when one reloads the page.

The [plunker link is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SWFgpp6ju07IwFB4XLB9?p=preview). If you launch the plunker preview on a seperate window, when you click the links, the url of the page changes as the corresponding view is rendered. However if the page is reloaded the page shows **Object not found!** error.

A relevant snippet for index.html is

```
<a href="Book/Moby">Moby</a> |
<a href="Book/Moby/ch/1">Moby: Ch1</a> |
```

Now if Moby is clicked the url of page shows `baseurl/Book/Moby` and the partial reloads. However if the page is reloaded then **Object Not Found error** comes.

The concerned part of code in script.js is

```
angular.module('ngRouteExample', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/Book/:bookId', {
    templateUrl: 'book.html',
    controller: 'BookController',
    resolve: {
      // I will cause a 1 second delay
      delay: function($q, $timeout) {
        var delay = $q.defer();
        $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
        return delay.promise;
      }
    }
  })
  .when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
    templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
    controller: 'ChapterController'
  });

  // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

How can I reload the partial view?

Comment: Wow this is a good question. I recreated a working angularJS ngRoute app and cannot reproduce the issue. My initial thought was something to do with the $locationProvider and the HTML5 mode. 
Anyways... it will be interesting to see what the answer is.

Comment: It so happens that at the server end, you gotta configure the server to return index.html for any route, then this'll work.